# Future continuous Vs future perfect continuous

Tags: tense, future-tense

It is about the future tense in English.

What is the difference between the future continuous and the future perfect continuous?

Examples:

- He will be tired because he will be exercising so hard.
- He will be tired because he will have been exercising so hard.

Comment: The latter sentence literally means : "He will be tired because he will have been exercising so hard at/by some point of time" which also implies that he will not be tired *until that period of time* and *a continuous action that has started before the consequence of exertion*. Or He will be tired because he will have been exercising so hard *for* some amount of time in the further future.

Answer (score -1):

In the first example you just stress the continuation of the process of exercising.
You could add the words: at 10 p.m tomorrow, for an hour, all day long, etc.

In the second one, you have to add some future point in time, and it would mean that by that point in time he'll have been exercising.

In 10 minutes, he'll be tired because he'll have been exercising so hard.
By 5:30 tomorrow, he'll be tired because he'll have been exercising so hard.